# Pandas match name to id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where there are name and id columns. In theory the name should always correspond to the same id, but due to some system errors and data quality issues in practice this is not always the case.

Generally the scenario is that the wrong id's occur at an extremely negligible rate compare to the right id's. So for example there will be a 1000 rows where the name 'a' and id '1' match but there will be 2 rows where the name is 'a' and id '7'.

So the logic to resolve what the proper id would simply be to find the most frequently occurring id for each name.

```
d = {'id': ['1', '1', '2', '2',], 'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'value': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df)
    store  name  value
0     1      a     1           
1     1      a     2               
2     2      a     3             
3     2      b     4
```

The first question is what is the best way to find the proper id for each name and drop the rows where the proper id does not occur, the result being the following:

```
    store  name  value
0     1      a     1            
1     1      a     2                             
2     2      b     4
```

The second part is, in the scenarios where the mismatched id is actually the id of another name, then fix the name to match the proper id, example output:

```
    store  name   value
0     1      a      1          
1     1      a      2
2     2      b      3              
3     2      b      4
```

**The actual data has thousands of names/ids, the example is just a simplification.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's a bit a makeshift job but it should work as a temporary solution

```
d = {'id': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3','3', '4', '4'],
     'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c'],
     'value': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Following the raw DataFrame, without id changes:

```
  id name value
0  1    a     1
1  1    a     2
2  2    a     3
3  2    b     4
4  2    b     5
5  3    b     6
6  3    c     7
7  4    c     8
8  4    c     9
```

Workflow:

```
# convert id, value from string to flat
df['id'] = [float(id) for id in df['id']]
df['value'] = [float(value) for value in df['value']]

# extract most repeated id for one name

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)


count = dict()
for name in pd.unique(df['name']):
    temp = {name: most_common(list(df[df['name'] == name]['id']))}
    count.update(temp)

# correct wrong id

replace = [[count[name], name] if id != count[name] else [id, name] for id, name in zip(df['id'],df['name'])]
df['id'] = [item[0] for item in replace]
df['name'] = [item[1] for item in replace]
```

output:

```
In [3]: count
Out[3]: {'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 4.0}

In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    id name  value
0  1.0    a    1.0
1  1.0    a    2.0
2  1.0    a    3.0
3  2.0    b    4.0
4  2.0    b    5.0
5  2.0    b    6.0
6  4.0    c    7.0
7  4.0    c    8.0
8  4.0    c    9.0
```

This solution might not work if you have the exact same count of two differents 'id' for the same 'name'